# How do I load multiple functions with jQuery Ajax content?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got a bunch of functions defined in an external js file like so:

```
function tabs() {
$(".tabs").tabs();
}

function closeOverlay() {
$(document).on('click','.close',function(event) {
    $(".overlay").fadeOut();
});
}
```

I'm using ajax to load content into my template, and need to load these functions along with it. This loads my content and my tabs function just fine:

```
$(document).on('click','#invite',function(event) {
    $(".overlay").fadeIn();
    $(".overlay").load("inc/invite-guests.htm",tabs);
});
```

But I can't figure out the syntax to load both my tabs function, and my closeOverlay function at the same time. I thought something like this would work, but it doesn't:

```
$(".overlay").load("inc/invite-guests.htm",tabs,closeOverlay);
```

Comment: First off, lets get terminology straight.  When you're passing a (callback) function to $.fn.load() you're not "loading" it, you're loading the content, and telling jQuery to execute your function after the content is loaded.  Now to answer your question, try this:
`$(".overlay").load("inc/invite-guests.htm",function({tabs();closeOverlay();});`

Comment: I tried it, but it shows errors.

$(document).on('click','#invite',function(event) {
 $(".overlay").fadeIn();
 $(".overlay").load("inc/invite-guests.htm",function({tabs();closeOverlay();});
});

Comment: Whoops, typo above, missing a `)`, try: `$(".overlay").load("inc/invite-guests.htm",function(){tabs();closeOverlay();});`

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't work. No errors, but it doesn't work. Overlay is always visible (despite having been hidden previously), and no content is loaded when #invite is clicked.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in each of your functions to see if they're being executed.  If they are, then it's probably an issue with timing or possibly binding to the wrong elements.  If you don't hit the breakpoints, then there's something else going on.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with what I have. It works fine if I just pass in "tabs", or "closeOverlay" by themselves. There's something wrong with your solution.

Comment: The solution works fine: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Waxen/xf3jz7xb/.  What you're doing in your original code is passing a function to  $.fn.load() for it to call once the ajax request is done.  What my code is doing is instead of passing your tabs or closeOverlay function, it's passing a function that calls each of those functions. If that isn't working, then there's something else going wrong.  If you can make a fiddle demonstrating your issue, I'll take a look, otherwise I can't do anything more to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out waxen's second answer does work:

```
$(".overlay").load("inc/invite-guests.htm",function() {  
tabs(); 
closeOverlay(); 
});
```

My browser must've been caching it.